# In case of Multiple DCs under a domain , how to connect to each and every domain Controller and read the LDAPs certifictae end date?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory

if we have high availability Domain Controller case (where there are multiple DCs) how to connect to each and every domain Controller and read the Ldap certifictae end date under a domain.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier with a shell script:

```
$ host ad.company.net > dcs.txt
$ openssl s_client ...:636
```

With that you can extract the certificate send by the backend and performs operations on.